# UIBarButtonItem not shown the same way in UIToolBar and UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I need to use a simple UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolBar.

I used this code to add the button with my custom image to the navigation bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cloneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sheep.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(clone)];
NSArray *rightItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cloneButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightItems;
```

The result is what I want and it looks like this

[navigation bar http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/3383/navigationbara.jpg](http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/3383/navigationbara.jpg)

When doing the same thing in a UIToolBar that I'm adding to a UITableViewCell's contentView

```
UIBarButtonItem *cloneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sheep.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(clone)];
UIBarButtonItem *leftSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftSpace, cloneButton, nil];
```

The problem is that I get something like this:

[toolbar http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/1374/toolbary.jpg](http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/1374/toolbary.jpg)

This is surely due to the fact that UINavigationBar and UIToolBar are not drawn the same way...
Can someone please point out how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how UIToolbar is supposed to work. Per the documentation:

> Toolbar images that represent normal and highlighted states of an item derive from the image you set using the inherited image property from the UIBarItem class. For example, the image is converted to white and then bevelled by adding a shadow for the normal state.

That said, you might be able to get the result you want by creating a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view instead of an image. Like so:

```
UIImage *sheepImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sheep.png"];
UIButton *sheepButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sheepButton setImage:sheepImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sheepButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sheepButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[sheepButton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *cloneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sheepButton];
```

I haven't tested this, so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: you're write, the taps aren't handled using a UIImageVIew but the image is like I want it except for the bordered style suggested by @WrightsCS. I had trouble with UIButton as I don't know how to assign the frame, so it actually doesn't appear on screen. Also when

Comment: I feel stupid not to have thought of sizeToFit (I usually use it only for UILabel). That made it! (without the bordered style as I've seen that it can't be used when using a customView)

Answer (score 2):

On your `UIToolbar` use  **`UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`** instead of **`UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`**.

`UINavigationBar` will not draw the button the same without the button look.

Comment: with the bordered style it actually makes the right look of the button, but the sheep image is still white

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the images posted in the question anymore. But I am pretty sure that we're trying to mimic the UIBarButtonItemStylePlain of the UIToolBar in a UINavigationBar.

Benzado is pretty much spot on except for this line:

```
[sheepButton setImage:sheepImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This puts the image in front of the touch indicator. The UIToolBar shows the touch in front of the image. So to mimic the UIToolBar style in a UINavigationBar:

```
UIImage *sheepImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sheep.png"];
UIButton *sheepButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sheepButton setBackgroundImage:sheepImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sheepButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sheepButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[sheepButton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *cloneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sheepButton];
```